# Count with multiple where conditions

Tags: sql

I thought this would have been really easy but I'm missing something.

Here's my data:

```
ID       EMPID    Index1
314      021576   5
315      021576   2
317      021576   8
318      021576   12
500      021576   398
501      021576   388
502      021111   4
503      021111   8
```

Here's my SQL statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS Expr1
    FROM ProfileData
    WHERE (Index1ID = 2) AND (Index1ID = 5)
```

I'm trying to get a count total of 1

Answer (score 3):

```
(Index1ID = 2) AND (Index1ID = 5)
```

Is a where clause which will always return false. If you mean for it to be `OR`, it would still not work, since it would return 2.

Comment: To expand just a bit, Yuriy is pointing out that Index1ID cannot simultaneously be two values at the same time.  What is the question you're trying to answer with this query?

Comment: It will be 1 if he changes to `or`. He is counting distinct EMPID.

Comment: But if I go. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS Expr1 FROM ProfileData WHERE (Index1ID = 2) or (Index1ID = 27). I still get a result of 1, it should be 0. Thats why I went with the AND

Comment: What I'm trying to answer is How many distinct emplIDs are there based on what index1ids I pass in the where. Might be 1, might be 10.

Comment: @cheezheadsrule in that case `OR` is right. And you get a result of 1 because there is only a row with Index1 of 2 and none with 27.

Comment: Is my syntax wrong or something. When I put an OR I still get 1. 

I should get 0. SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT EmpID) AS Expr1 FROM RADProfileData WHERE (Index1ID = 2) OR (Index1ID = 27)

Comment: @cheezheadsrule your syntax is right, it seems your conclusion is wrong. Based on the data I'm seeing, I agree with the database that you should get 1.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you want to know the number of `EMPID` values that have both a row with an `Index1ID` value of 2 and an Index1 value of 5 (`EMPID` 021576 has both, `EMPID` 021111 has neither).  There are a variety of ways to do this

Using set operations

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT empid)
  FROM (SELECT empid
          FROM ProfileData
         WHERE Index1ID = 2 
        INTERSECT
        SELECT empid
          FROM ProfileData
         WHERE Index1ID = 5)
```

Or using a GROUP BY

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT empid)
  FROM (SELECT empid, COUNT(DISTINCT Index1ID) cnt
          FROM ProfileData
         WHERE Index1ID IN (2,5)
         GROUP BY empid)
 WHERE cnt = 2
```

If you wanted the list of `EMPID` values that are associated with both `Index1ID` values, that's easier with the HAVING clause

```
SELECT empid, COUNT(DISTINCT Index1ID)
  FROM ProfileData
 WHERE Index1ID IN (2,5)
 GROUP BY empid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Index1ID) = 2
```

Comment: This last query gives me what I'm looking for. As always thanks everyone for their excellent help!!!